# Direct way to convert org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration to java.util.Properties

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons-config

I am able to convert `org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration` to `java.util.Properties` using:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(fileName);
Iterator iter = config.getKeys();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iter.next();
    String value = config.getString(key);
    props.put(key, value);
}
```

**Assumption:** keys and values are of String type.

Is there any direct way to convert `Configuration` to `Properties`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ConfigurationConverter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationConverter.html) should do the job .

It has those two methods to convert in both directions :

> **Configuration   getConfiguration(Properties props)**
>
> Convert a standard Properties class into a configuration class

and

> **Properties  getProperties(Configuration config)**
>
> Convert a Configuration
>   class into a Properties class.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks..:)